# Balancing two options by multiple opposing arguments, alternatives to "on the one hand ... on the other hand"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests, metaphors

Is it possible to use the construction *on the one hand ... on the other hand* with multiple complex arguments supporting two opposing options? I have doubts. Usually it looks like this:

"On the one hand, *she is a good cook*, on the other hand, *she constantly smells of burned fat*. So it is one to one."

I have a bit complex mathematical optimization problem and I would like to state it clearly:

"The most profitable inventory level requires *balancing* losses in storage costs, product obsolescence, and capital employed *on the one hand* ***against*** lost sales opportunities due to insufficient product availability *on the other hand*."

So I am *balancing* excessive inventory costs *against* insufficient inventory risks. I have doubts if using "hands" metaphor is appropriate at all. In my home language we have a useful metaphor of a weighing pan:

*balancing on the one scale* ... *against* ... *on the opposite scale*

By using this metaphor we can stuff the scales with numerous things without losing clarity.

Comment: 'On the other hand' has reached the status of 'dead metaphor': very few would think of the physical object when using / reading it. Metaphors are by definition devices using comparators that don't correspond overall.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For me it isn't so dead as to still sound OK when you introduce a third option with "but on the third hand...". To address the question, you can have a list of things "on the one hand, but on the other hand" another list of things.

Comment: Your sentence [*"The most profitable inventory level requires balancing losses in storage costs, product obsolescence, and capital employed on the one hand against lost sales opportunities due to insufficient product availability on the other hand."*] would read perfectly well without any references to hands.

Comment: @Rosie F The test for deadness is not whether a metaphor may undergo variation idiomatically, but whether people think about the compositionality of the usual version. A tough problem, but not a tender problem. Fly off the handle, but not fly back onto the handle. // I'm addressing 'So I am balancing [A] excessive inventory costs against [B] insufficient inventory risks. I have doubts if using "hands" metaphor is appropriate at all.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You make my point for me. For me, "On the one hand, X, but on the other hand, Y, but on the third hand, Z" sounds off to me not because the three-item variation isn't idiomatic as such, but exactly because the wording reminds me of hands, and that restricts the idiom to two items.

Comment: @RosieF There is no third hand, with a small exception to Adam Smith's invisible hand. In my question I mean two hands but each hand supported by multiple arguments. On the one hand she is A, B, C, on the other hand she is D, E, F.

Comment: Try [_the gripping hand_](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/O/on-the-gripping-hand.html).

Comment: This particular example seems to me like one of the cases I personally might retain the “hands”, but I think you have a general point. For some reason non-native speakers seem to overuse this — judging by my observation of fluent scientists in an international research institute. I’ll make any suggestions in an answer. @RichardKayser — I’d generally agree with “cut out the flab”, but I think it has a function as a separator in this kind of sentence. Of course, if the sentence is too long… (I don’t have to tell you.)

Comment: @David I think *balancing* and *against* covers it. No need for a separator. Superfluous. :-)

Comment: @RichardKayser — Yes, you’re right.

Comment: If you have any other suggestion to the weighing word with separator similar to pair _Balancing ... against_ for example like _Sacrificing ... for_ or _Trading ... for_, please share.

Comment: Numerous possibilities, e.g.: "The most profitable inventory level occurs (or results) when losses in storage costs, product obsolescence, and capital employed on the one hand equal lost sales opportunities due to insufficient product availability on the other hand." This one preserves your references to hands and fixes the problem that "the most profitable inventory level" can not really "require".

Answer (score 3):

Balancing already suggests scales, so even your home language metaphor is redundant. Similarly, you don't need any hands at all:

> *The most profitable inventory level requires balancing [**this**] against [**that**].*
> *The most profitable inventory level requires balancing **losses in storage costs, product obsolescence, and capital employed** against **lost sales opportunities due to insufficient product availability**.*

Your [this] and [that], though, complicate the sentence. Maybe you can tighten things up a bit (and move *capital employed* so *employed* doesn't try to be a verb):

> *The most profitable inventory level requires balancing **storage cost losses, capital employed, and product obsolescence** against **lost sales due to insufficient inventory**.*

Finally, I think this is what you're actually trying to say:

> ***Finding** the most profitable inventory level requires **weighing** storage cost losses, capital employed, and product obsolescence **against** lost
> sales due to insufficient inventory.*

Comment: Absolutely right. :) Keep it simple to make it good.

Comment: I do not agree, though I am grateful. The goal is to explain the problem to a layman, not to write it down mathematically in the most succinct way. The metaphor is helpful in presenting the inverse relationship, and its structure "hand-hand" allows for the clear separation of the forces that pull us up from those that pull us down.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin: If this is for the layperson, it should be simpler yet:  *Finding the most profitable inventory level requires weighing—on one hand—the cost of acquiring and storing a product that may become outdated, against—on the other—lost sales due to stocking shortages.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat yeap, I like it. Simple words, and structure also contributes to clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following?

> The most profitable inventory level requires finding the best compromise between losses in storage costs, product obsolescence, capital employed and lost sales opportunities due to insufficient product availability.

Comment: Thank you for that "compromise". I still think that "weighing pan with scales" is a good metaphor because it states clearly that the gain on one side implies an inevitable loss on the other side. This reversed relation may not be linear or proportional as scales suggest but definitely it informs that you cannot have a gain without a loss. Compromise on the other hand :-) does not bring this "trade off" to mind. However when you wrote it I thought of a "sacrifice." Sacrifice implies hopes for gain but no taint of linearity.